# I need some assistance in figuring out a photo processing technique

Tags: post-processing

I am a fan of the [this photo stream](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dkitch/), but I'm having a difficult time recreating the processing techniques.

Does anyone know which techniques are used? The only thing I know is that the photos are processed in Photoshop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you see? Outside of over-sharpening, I do not see much in common with all but the last image.

Comment: If its the first two that the question is about, it looks like there has been some RGB curves work done. I'm not sure they have all had that much sharpening either...a bit, but I wouldn't say they are oversharpened...some of them have that nice, smooth, soft quality that is so appealing.

Comment: It's extremely likely that the photostream will change as new photos are added. Can you link to the exact ones you want to talk about? Describing the effect would be helpful too, both so we can know what you see and are interested in, and to help future people who may be looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Those first three pictures are tone poems, or that's how I think of photos like these.  So look at the first one.

I see lower total overall range, this histogram is very skewed and without pure blacks or clear whites it gets a hazy or dreamy quality.

Tone mapping, almost a classical Sepia tone but mixed 50%.

Something for local contrast, I think, to help with the curve of the face.

The out of focus areas before and after the main plane at the man almost looks like one of those "oil paint" gimmick filters lightly applied... adding to the hazy but sharp look.

My best guesses anyways,  it's been a while since I've done any hardcore image manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

These effects are achievable in Lightroom. Of, course, you need to have good photos (good colors, lighting, setting, etc) for these. Anyway, have you tried asking the photographer? I'm sure some are happy to share their techniques if you ask politely.